# sklearn.accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict) vs np.mean(y_predict == y_test)

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, accuracy

What is the difference between these two methods for finding model accuracy?

I have used both methods in python3 and i normally get identical results. However in few cases i get completely different results, so I am trying to figure out the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these methods act differently. You will only get the same results in very few cases or if you are testing only one row at a time.

- `np.mean(y_test==y_pred)` first checks if all the values in y_test is
  equal to corresponding values in y_pred which either results in 0 or 1. And then takes the mean of it (which is still 0 or 1).
- `accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)` counts all the indexes where an element
  of y_test equals to an element of y_pred and then divide it with the total number of elements in the list.

For example-

```
  import numpy as np
  from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
  y_test = [2,2,3]
  y_pred = [2,2,1]
  print(accuracy_score( y_test, y_pred))
  print(np.mean(y_test==y_pred))
```

This code returns -

```
  0.6666666666666666
  0.0
```

You will get the same result from both the method if you have only one sample/element to test. You can find more details here on [accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#accuracy-score) and [np.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html).

Also, accuracy_score is only for classification data. As mentioned in the first line [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score).

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that to gauge the accuracy of my RandomForest CLassifier I should use accuracy_score() rather than np.mean?

Comment: @codiearcher Yes but I would suggest you to also look at [confusion_matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) to evaluate the overall results of your model rather than just accuracy.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I am already using a confusion matrix, as well as checking prec, recall and F1.

Comment: @codiearcher Glad to help.

Comment: You are assuming that y_test and y_pred are lists. If they are dataframe columns, then the two methods are identica.